# One button circuit with thyristor, controling power suply

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, thyristor, ws2812b

Please forgive my lack of knowlige.
I need to make circuit with one button(normaly OFF, ON while pressing) using thyristor.
This circuit will be connecting and disconnecting raspberry pi and bunch of LEDs(16x16 ws2812b panel) from power suply.
I was imagining something like: pressing button first time: supply is connected, pressing button for second time: supply is disconnected and so on.
I cant use switch instead( it has to be a circuit).
I want one other led to indicate if its ON or OFF.
I also dont know what values should i use for components.
I will probably use 5V 10A supply but I dont know if resistors and thyristor survive that.
Here is my wild guess:
[image]

I will appreciate any help.
It shouldnt be mutch more comlicated than this(i found some alternatives with 2 buttons but i will prefere with 1 button).
I am also sorry if missed something similar and this is a duplicate.

Comment: You are missing an understanding of the basic function of a thyristor. Once gated, it continues to conduct after the gate signal is removed until it is reverse biased for its turn-off time, or the source current is interrupted.

Comment: Do you really "need" to do this with a thyristor?

Comment: I need something similarly complicated it dont have to be with thyristor. I also know the circuit on the picture is not working, I just found it somewhere.

Comment: You may want to change your question then. Also, searching for "soft latching switch" here on EE should give you some ideas and answers, like this one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304133/need-a-soft-latching-power-on-off-that-starts-off

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for something like this recently. I came across this setup and worked it out.
The schematic in the picture has been confirmed on a breadboard, only not with an actual microprocessor (Arduino) but with myself doing the GPIO-pin CTRL-things (connecting to 5V HIGH or GND/LOW).
I've been adding some pinout descriptions for clarification to myself.
[image]